# What exactly does "An internal error occurred during: "ProjectName". null argument:" mean? Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically I'm new to Java. I'm taking a CS course and have a very base knowledge, but in practice it's next to nothing. I'm getting the error "An internal error occurred during: "Launching ShapesAndFigures".
null argument:" while trying to run it and I'm really not sure why or what this means. Running in Eclipse.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;


        public class ShapesAndFigures {

            private Scanner typeInput;

            public String GetType() {
                String type;
                typeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("[Circle]");
                type = typeInput.nextLine();
                return type;
            }
    
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new ShapesAndFigures().GetType();
            }

        }
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your (guessing) Eclipse setup rather than a problem with your code.

Comment: I don't know, how you got the message, but: if you copy that code into a file named ShapesAndFigures.java in a folder x. Navigate to folder x with `cmd.exe` (if using Windows). Call `javac ShapesAndFigures.java` and then `java -cp . ShapesAndFigures`. Your code just works fine. Not the best code, but if prints out [Circle].

Comment: Using an IDE, maybe you misconfigured your java runtime. Try configuring that one and rerun the class.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Actually best old way was to close eclipse and open once again.

Now it is fine